# How to draw on a texture using SDL2_gfx in SDL2 and then render?

Tags: c, graphics, sdl, sdl-2

I want to implement a MS-Paint-like program (although my actual program will do more than this) where one can draw using mouse.

I am using `SDL2` and also `SDL2_gfx`.

I want to maintain an `SDL_Texture` where the user will do the drawing in a continuously way without clearing (unless requested by the user) at any time.

And then continuously update the `SDL_Texture` on to the screen.

**My question specifically is how to draw `SDL2_gfx primitives` on the `SDL_Texture` and copy that to the renderer. Any completely different way than to use texture will also do for me but must be using SDL2.**

Below is a minimal runnable extraction from my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h>

#define WIDTH (320)
#define HEIGHT (240)

SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
SDL_RendererInfo rendererInfo;
SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;
SDL_Event event;
Sint16 cx = WIDTH/2, cy = HEIGHT/2;
uint8_t quit = 0;

void init()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL, &window, &renderer);
    texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, WIDTH, HEIGHT); // create texture to draw on to
    // SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, texture); // this one I have removed
}

void draw()
{
    pixelRGBA(renderer, cx, cy, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff); // draw a pixel here, or whatever cx and cy are mouse position
    // what I want is to draw on to the texture, and not directly on the screen buffer
}

void render()
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255); // set clear color
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer); // clear the buffer
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL); // now copy the drawn texture to the buffer
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); // now update window
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int p;
    init();
    while(!quit)
    {
        SDL_PumpEvents();
        p = SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        if(p>0)
        {
            if(event.type==SDL_QUIT) quit = 1;
            else
            {
                // here other things are there to handle the mouse positions etc for drawing exactly what the user wants
                // ...
                draw();
                render();
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't specified `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET` as a texture access flag, then didn't reset renderer to screen and back to texture again. https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTexture is a good example.

Comment: @keltar: Could you please explain in a little more detailed way.

Comment: @keltar: Many thanks I did this and it works: 

In init():

`    texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, texture);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);`

In draw():

` SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, texture);
    pixelRGBA(renderer, cx, cy, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
`